# Copying only the changed files while mirroring a website

Tags: php, javascript, web-applications, curl, wget

I am using wget to mirror  website using this code

```
$ wget \
     --recursive \
     --no-clobber \
     --page-requisites \
     --html-extension \
     --convert-links \
     --restrict-file-names=windows \
     --domains website.org \
     --no-parent \
         www.website.org/tutorials/html/
```

The next time I run it it starts downloading the same files again, however I want only the changed files to be downloaded next time. I am open to use any other tool or script(preferably PHP,Curl) apart from using wget.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is tailor-made job for rsync. See [man rsync](http://ss64.com/bash/rsync.html)

You can use:

```
rsync -avz <source> <destination>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the option `--timestamping` for an incremental download. Also see [wget manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#Time_002dStamping) for further information.